# CAS proxy ticket validate missing proxy information

Tags: cas

I am trying to implement CAS proxy mechanism as described in https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Proxy+CAS+Walkthrough. I am able to get the proxy ticket (but it starts with a ST- instead of a PT-as shown in the example). I am able to validate the proxy ticket as well. The response for the proxy validate (an service validate) are not as per the xml format mentioned in the example - plain text (with login Id and username) is returned back. I am trying to fetch the proxy information specifically to understand the source of the request at the service side.

Is there some CAS configuration that I am missing?

Comment: Chrome converted the cas response xml and just showed text, i was able to see the complete response xml in view source mode, but proxy list was still missing